# How get string from inside of tag with specyfic class

Tags: javascript

How to pass whats inside of tag with `myClass` class as a string here?

```
function przyciskRozpoczynajacyEdycje() { 
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
    for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
        items[i].addEventListener("click", function () { passIdToEdit('How to put here whats inside tag with class "myClass"?') });
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `this.innerHTML`? Inside an event handler `this` is the associated object of the event, in this case the HTML element:

```
items[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    passIdToEdit(this.innerHTML);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function przyciskRozpoczynajacyEdycje() { 
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
    items[i].addEventListener("click", function () 
 { passIdToEdit(items[i].inerText) });
}
}​
```

Comment: in the passIdToEdit() function you would want to use items[i] instead of items[0] otherwise you will receive undesired results when the for loop is iterated through

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
function przyciskRozpoczynajacyEdycje() { 
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
    var myId = items[i].innerText;
    items[i].addEventListener("click", function () { passIdToEdit(myId) });
}
```

}​

Answer (score 0):

```
items[i].innerHTML; //returns the html (if more than text is used [ex. in a div]) within the tag
```